# How to display distinct data from MySql in dropdownlist box using C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Here I am trying to load the dropdownlist box from a column of a table in Mysql(which contains repeated values), so I need to get unrepeated values.

This is my code:

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Connection String"); 
MysqlCommand cmd;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    cn.Open();
    cmd = cn.createcommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Columnname from tablename"; 
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {                
       while (reader.Read())
       {
           DropDownList.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Columnname"));    
       }
     }    
     cn.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing your SQL query to get `DISTINCT` results

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Columnname FROM tablename";
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion helped me out but it is accepting the empty field also can you help me out in that.

Comment: You could try adding a WHERE clause to remove that. Is it a blank string or a NULL? Try adding 'WHERE Columnname <> '' AND Columnname IS NOT NULL'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and i tried it, but its not working.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there an unwanted blank field, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is then presumably called more than once, maybe on each post back. Just clear the items first:

```
DropDownList.Items.Clear();
```

One thing to note is that when `ViewState` is enabled there is no need to reload your drop down lists on each subsequent post back. That also means that you can decide rather to execute this code *only if* `if (!this.IsPostBack`)`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply but i have repeated values in my selected column so i need to get all the values but only once i mean if a particular value retrieved once then should not be repeated again.

Comment: @user246354, I'm sorry but I do not understand what you're saying.

Comment: Its ok but your suggestion helped me out in some other issue thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

table1:

**id                 name**

1                            saravanan
2                            karumbasalam G
3                            saravanan

**select distinct name from table1**

output: 
        
       **name**
                 saravanan
                karumbasalam G

**Use the `distinct` keyword used to avoid duplicates**